# How do I print if someone is or not eligible to vote by using nested if statement?

Tags: java, nested-if

I'm trying to print simple lines of text using nested if statement.
but somehow relational symbols return an always false:

```
//unfinished
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exe6 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your age for verification: ");
        int verify = sc.nextInt();

        if (verify >= 18){
            System.out.println("You are eligible to vote.");
            if (verify <= 17) {                                    //always false
                System.out.println("Minors are ineligible to vote");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think my brain is not braining and my logic has some problems. please show me the way.

Comment: Clearly, if `verify >= 18`, then it can never be `<= 17`.  You do NOT want a nested if statement here.  You want an `if` with a simple `else` clause.

Comment: At an intersection, if you turn left, you can no longer see the scenery on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use an `else`. If `verify >= 18` is false, then `verify` is necessarily less than or equal to `17`, so you don't need to write the condition again. Nesting is also incorrect here because the inner `if` statement will only be run if the first condition was true, i.e. `verify` is at least 18 (and thus is never `<= 17`).

```java
if (verify >= 18) {
    System.out.println("You are eligible to vote.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Minors are ineligible to vote");
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for explaining it in layman's term

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple else if the above condition is not true it will directly give the output or you can use else if too..
In line 7 there should be println...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The content that follows the *if-conditional* statement, within the brackets, `{ }`, is called a *scope*—also referred to as a *code-block*.

A matching *conditional statement* will enter the scope, whereas a failing *conditional statement* will skip to after the scope.

Thus, testing for *verify >= 18* will determine whether the scope code will be executed or not.

So, when *verify* is below *18*, the program will skip to after the scope, and, in this case, exit the program.

You'll need to move the inner *if-conditional*, to outside of it's current scope.

```java
if (verify >= 18){
    System.out.println("You are eligible to vote.");
}

if (verify <= 17) {                                    //always false
    System.out.println("Minors are ineligible to vote");
}
```

Here is a documentation on *if-conditional statements*, by Java.
*[The if-then and if-then-else Statements (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)*.

Additionally, here is a *Wikipedia* article on *control-flow*, the term used for data mitigation—e.g., *if-statements*.
*[Wikipedia – Control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)*.

Comment: thank you for laying out detailed explanation